# iTextSharp font tag not working with XMLWorker class

Tags: itext

I’m using itextsharp 5.3.5 and xml worker to generate the PDF from my html page. In my html page I have a rich text editor which generate the html using the div tags and font tags. Please see the below html piece generated by my field.

```
<html xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div>
        this text is not <strong>working</strong>
    </div>
    <div>
        <font color="#ff0000">text in Red now</font>.
    </div>
    <div>
        <font face="Tahoma" size="5">a font thoma and size 5.</font>
    </div>
    <div>
        <font face="Tahoma" size="5">
            <font face="Arial" size="3">here is a link to </font>
            <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/">
                <font face="Arial" size="3">Google</font>
            </a>.
        </font>
    </div>
</html>
```

I found that if I use html worker instead then it converts the above html perfectly in pdf. But not the xml worker. It just didn’t work.

I also found that if I change some of the tags and update my html like below, then xml worker converts it in pdf.

```
<p>this text is not <strong>working</strong></p>
<span style="color:#ff0000">text in Red now</span>.
        <br />
        <span style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:5">a font thoma and size 5.</span>
        <br/>
        <span style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:5">
          <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:3">here is a link to </span><a href="http://www.google.co.uk/">
            <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:3">Google</span>
          </a>.
        </span>
        <br />
```

Now obviously I can’t change the html tags on run time, it will be a big mess. My code is as below.

```
StringReader html = new StringReader(htmlString);
var xmlWorkerFontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
var cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(xmlWorkerFontProvider);
CssFilesImpl cssFiles = new CssFilesImpl(); 
cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCSS()); 
StyleAttrCSSResolver cssRevolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers); 
htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
PdfWriterPipeline pdfWriterPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssRevolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdfWriterPipeline)); 
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);                 
XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);
xmlParser.Parse(html);
```

I would really appreciate if you can guide me, how I can convert the above html in pdf using the xml worker.

If you need any further information, please do let me know.